# How To Get Key Of goDaddy

Tags: ios, objective-c, url, webview, url-shortener

Actually I want to created application of shortening URL , i have used GoDady by creating account at http://app.x.co/  But My URL doesnot get shorten.

This is my key

```
#define kGoDaddyAccountKey @"b201137c009311e6984efa163ee12fa9"
```

This is actually The method that do work for Shortening URL

```
- (IBAction)shortenURL:(id)sender
{
  NSString *urlToShorten = self.webView.request.URL.absoluteString;
    NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://api.x.co/Squeeze.svc/text/%@?url=%@",kGoDaddyAccountKey,
                           [urlToShorten stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

shortURLData = [NSMutableData new];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
    shortenURLConnection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request
                                                         delegate:self];

}
```

But I get error like This.

[image]

Quite Interesting, Please Help.

Comment: what u want in goDaddy url?

Comment: This app uses GoDaddy's free, and public, X.co URL shortening service.
// To use it, programmatically, we must  provide the server an account "key"

Comment: can you show ur full error report

Comment: It's like this : {"status" : 422,"code" : "CREATE_ERROR","fields" : [{"path" : "shopper_id","code" : "SHOPPER_NO_PURCHASE"}]} @Anbu.Karthik